# ny Example about How map method accepting Array as argument?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I saw in MDN definition syntax that i can pass Array as argument in the callback function but there is no example clear how ?
This option founded in alot of methods like **map() , forEach() , some()**:

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
//your iterator
}[, thisArg]);
```

---

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

Can You help by code example passing Array as arg?
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about the third @array argument which is passed to the callback? This is simply the array being iterated over / mapped, in case you wanted to reference it in your callback.

Comment: You have checked the documentation, however the information is clearly ... there. If you want to use the array in your callback, then access the third argument. It is essentially the `arr` in your example.

Comment: ohh, I thought it referring to another array not this invoked ..
You mean it's the same array that method invoked it @Utkanos

Comment: thanks @KarelG I'm still beginner and sometime confused in translation specially when no example clear

Comment: @AymanMorsy Yes, that's correct. I'll post it up as an answer so you can accept. Easy to be confused sometimes. Plenty of MDN articles don't fully explain or demonstrate specific techniques or use of parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is merely a reference to the outer array that you're iterating over/mapping.

It's passed automatically as the third argument to your callback, whether or not you reference or use it.

```
['foo', 'bar'].forEach(function(val, index, arr) {
    console.log(arr.join()); //"foo,bar";
});
```

Comment: really Thanks ...was very helpful for me . see 
['foo', 'bar'].forEach(function(val, index, arr) {
  const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
    console.log(arr.reduce(reducer)); //"foobar";
});